# How can I list numbers within a certain group whose remainder will be the same if divided by the same number?

Tags: r

If I want to list down numbers between 1 to 100, which will have a remainder of 3 if divided by 9, how can I code it?

Answer (score 2):

we can do this with basic operadors and without a loop:

```
d <- 1:100

d[d%%9==3]
3 12 21 30 39 48 57 66 75 84 93
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here to suggest the following, knowing that loops are generally not a good idea:

```
for (i in 1:100){
  if ((i%%9)==3) print(i)
}
```

Same use of modulus operator (`%%`), but DPH's response is much cleaner.  Use that.